# Let $A=\{1,2,...,10\}$ and $B=\{41,42,...,50\}$. Find number of subsets of $S$, which have non-empty intersection with both $A$ and $B$.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Let $S=\{1,2,...,100\}$ and let $A=\{1,2,...,10\}$ and $B=\{41,42,...,50\}$. What is the total number of subsets of $S$, which have non-empty intersection with both $A$ and $B$.

**My Attempt:**

Let $C$ be the desired subset.

Number of ways to select atleast one element from $A$ is $2^{10}-1$ and from $B$ is also $2^{10}-1$ .

And the remaining $80$ elements have $2$ choices each i.e. they may be in C or they may not be in $C$.

So total number of possible subsets is $2^{80}\left(2^{10}-1\right)^2$

Is it correct? Can the problem be solved by some other method

Comment: That looks correct and I'd say your method was optimal.  As an alternative, you could go by Inclusion Exclusion:  $2^{100}-2\times 2^{90}+2^{80}$.  Note that this is easily seen to match your result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Logic:** Instead of finding non empty intersection subsets of S with both A and B, we will find empty subsets then subtract from all subsets

Given
S = { 1,2,3 ....100}
A = { 1,2,3 ...10}
B = { 41,42,43 ...50}

Let C = { 1,2, ...40,51,52,53...100}

Clearly $A, B, C$ are disjoint sets

Now
D = { 1,2,3,....40,51,52,53...100}
B $\cap$ D = $\phi$

E = { 11,12,13,...100}
A $\cap$ E = $\phi$

So set D form empty intersection with B and E form empty intersection with A

Number of subsets forms empty intersection with S are D or E

$n(P( D\cup E)) = n(P(D)) + n(P(E)) - n(P(D\cap E)$
$n(P( D\cup E)) = 2^{90} +  2^{90} - 2^{80}$

(Since $D\cap E = C$)

$n(P( D\cup E)) = 2 \times 2^{90} - 2^{80}$

Subtract All subsets of $S$ n empty intersection subsets

$=n(P(S)) - nP(D\cap E)$
$=2^{100} - (2 \times 2^{90} - 2^{80})$
$=2^{100} - 2 \times 2^{90} + 2^{80})$
$=2^{80}(2^{20}  - 2 \times 2^{10} + 1)$
$=2^{80}(2^{10} - 1)^2$

Using the identity
$(a-b)^2 = a^2 - 2ab +b^2$